# Backbone model (collection) change event does not fire

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Can anyone explain to my why the change event never fires in my code? Similar questions have been asked before, but were no help to me. I suppose there is a general mistake in my code which I am not seeing.

```
item = Backbone.Model.extend({});
itemCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({model:item, url:"/get.json/data?query=getcol"});

search=Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#searchView"),
         events: { 
        'keypress #search_query' : 'lookup', 
        'click #search_button' : 'lookup', 

    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.model = new itemCollection;
        this.model.on("change", this.render, this);     
    }, 
    render: function() { 
        now=new Date().getTime(); /*used to make render() calls visible*/
        json = JSON.stringify(this.model);
        $("#searchResults").html(json + " " + now); 
    }, 
    lookup: function() { 
        this.model.url = "/get.json/data?query=" + $("#search_query").val();
        this.model.fetch();

    }
});
searchview = new search;
```

(The path "/get.json/data?query=" is correct.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a collection is fetched, a `sync` event is triggered. So change

> model.on("change", this.render, this)

to

> model.on("sync", this.render, this)

It's also a good idea to rename `this.model` to `this.collection` in your code for clarity. Also consider using the [listenTo](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) event so that the event is cleaned up when your view is removed.

```
this.listenTo(this.collection, "sync", this.render, this)
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the variable naming is misleading, but I'm just playing around with Backbone..